# Structuring a booking website

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, vs-web-site-project

I am very new to web development, and I'm trying to get my head around the most efficient method in creating the website.

The premise of the website is for booking activities in various locations. Processes I believe that would take place are:

- Customer books activity;
- Request updates database, and request is sent to vendor;
- If vendor approves request, confirmation is sent to customer in the form of QR code, barcode, and numerical code (for redemption);
- If approved, customer is charged the amount of the activity.

My question is what structure should I use in approaching this problem? My thoughts at the moment is placing the website in Google' app engine, using mySQL database.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "most efficient" should come well after "working and tested"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GAE, I suggest looking into NDB Datastore. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

1. Customer books activity → a) store in ndb datastore and b) verify that information → send to vendor
2. Confirmation (display URL code e.g. http://website.com/?c=generaterandomlongstringhere)
3. If URL is clicked, you can add a confirm as well after like accept | decline (e.g. http://website.com/?c=generaterandomlongstringhere&?v=acceptordecline)
4. Update NDB and Charge user